# Shortcut in Eclipse PDT to "require" a file?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-pdt

I'm working with a large codebase using eclipse PDT and often need to add a lot of require_once statements at the beginning of the file. Are there any shortcuts (as there are in eclipse JDT) to do this? It would be super helpful if I could avoid always having to write out the path of a file each time I would like to include one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the editor type `req` and hit **Ctrl+Space**. This (`Ctrl+Space`) will pop up the auto-complete suggestions from which you can choose require_once.

Also, update to the last version of PDT. When I write `req` it offers automatically to choose `require` *or* `require_once`.